# Форматирование PHP кода в Visual Studio Code с помощью расширения php-cs-fixer

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, format

Установил расширение php-cs-fixer

Подключил правила

```
"php-cs-fixer.rules": "@PhpCsFixer"
```

Форматирование работает, но исправляет код, например

```
if ($pass == '')
```

на такой

```
if ('' == $pass)
```

Это дико раздражает. Как исправить?

@u_mulder, я нашел такой текст в двух местах:

`C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\friendsofphp\php-cs-fixer\src\RuleSet.php`

и

```
C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\friendsofphp\php-cs-fixer\src\Fixer\LanguageConstruct\IsNullFixer.php
```

правка не помогает.

Comment: Найти нужное правило и исправить, называется оно `yoda_style`

Comment: @u_mulder, я дописал в вопрос, ато тут нечитабельно

Comment: Не пробовал мануалов почитать - https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/blob/2.18/doc/config.rst? Может тогда бы разобрался что конфиг фиксера лежит в `.php_cs.dist` файле.